# Determining Screen Density

Tags: android, constants, dpi

Brand new to stackoverflow, haven't figured out how to ask a question within a thread.

This is for thread: [How to find the device as LDPI MDPI HDPI or XHDPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061238/how-to-find-the-device-as-ldpi-mdpi-hdpi-or-xhdpi)

The code used is:

```
int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

switch(density) {
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
  Toast.makeText(context, "LDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
  Toast.makeText(context, "MDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
  Toast.makeText(context, "HDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
  Toast.makeText(context, "XHDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
}
```

My phone (LG Optimus L5) reports MDPI (160) even though tech specs state 144dpi, which is fine since it works perfectly with the code.  However, my Google Nexus 7 reports 213dpi which doesn't match a constant and I can't find a reference to borders of densities.

A work around (I believe, new to Android) would be to put a hidden constant in the layouts in the density layout folders and check the constant in code to see which density constant is being used.

The question is:  Can I determine this value within code without the constant in the layouts with devices reporting values not matching the constants?

Thanks

Comment: "my Google Nexus 7 reports 213dpi which doesn't match a constant" -- [yes, it does](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_TV). "with devices reporting values not matching the constants" -- what are you planning on doing that requires the exact density instead of the general density bucket?

Answer (score 1):

A report of **213** is `DENSITY_TV`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_TV

Answer (score 0):

I also own a Google Nexus 7 and I know it has [tvdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028697/android-tvdpi-vs-xhdpi-screen-issue) density.